# Kohonen SOM for high (50-100) dimensions

Tags: high-dimensional, self-organizing-maps

Does a Kohonen-style SOM, using Euclidean distance, work as well as, better than, or worse than alternatives (K-means, etc) in high (50-100 or more) dimensional space? EDIT: I'm thinking particularly of the *curse of dimensionality* and distances in high dimensions and wondering if SOM's (2D) neuron network -- and its resulting elasticity -- improves or worsens the situation -- perhaps with large SOMS (thousands of nodes) or perhaps not.

I've been experimenting with R's `kohonen` package, and particularly its supervised `xyf` function, if that makes a difference. I've been using a 40x40 SOM with about 100K training points.

I like the idea of a supervised method, but I've also been experimenting with the `Rsomoclu` package, which is unsupervised but is fast enough to allow much higher SOM dimensions (experimenting with 100x100 and higher). I've read that SOMs with thousands of nodes begin to enable emergent properties. But it's still a 50-100-dimensional Euclidean space.

Comment: I think the number of nodes of the SOM doesn't really matter (well, training will take a long time), but rather the dimensions of the weight vector of the node as Euclidean distance couldn't really handle high dimensions.